# set the Actionbar in TabHost Activity of android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to set the ActionBar to a tab activity in android. i tried a lot.
But can't solve this topic. i'm using the Tab Activity, i want to display actionbar above the tabhost. How can I add actionbar in this activity?

I'm using the android studio and sdk is 25

here is my code:

```
package com.example.lenovo.monitoringapp;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class KwhActivity extends TabActivity {

    TabHost TabHostWindow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kwh);
        TabHostWindow = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        TabSpec TabMenu1 = TabHostWindow.newTabSpec("Graph");
        TabSpec TabMenu2 = TabHostWindow.newTabSpec("Data List");

        TabMenu1.setIndicator("Graph");
        Intent intent = new Intent(KwhActivity.this, GraphActivity.class);
    //    intent.putExtra("uname", username);
        // Set tab 1 activity to tab 1 menu.
        TabMenu1.setContent(intent);

        // Setting up tab 2 name.
        TabMenu2.setIndicator("Data List");
        Intent i1 = new Intent(KwhActivity.this, DataListActivity.class);

      //  i1.putExtra("uname", username);
        // Set tab 3 activity to tab 1 menu.
        TabMenu2.setContent(i1);


        TabHostWindow.addTab(TabMenu1);
        TabHostWindow.addTab(TabMenu2);
    }






    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.kwhactivity, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_other1:

                AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(KwhActivity.this);
                builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.calender);
                builderSingle.setTitle("Select");

                final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(KwhActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);
                arrayAdapter.add("Today");
                arrayAdapter.add("Yesterday");
                arrayAdapter.add("Week");
                arrayAdapter.add("30 Days");
                arrayAdapter.add("Year");

                builderSingle.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);

                        if(strName == "Today")
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(KwhActivity.this, "Today!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            builderSingle.show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Here is **activity_main.xml** file

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: TabHost is deprecated!

Comment: follow this [android-material-design-working-with-tabs](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) it will sure help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  Toolbar above TabHost by using below code;

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```